# How to properly use NumericTextBox for the numbers with decimal points

Tags: javascript, shieldui, numeric-textbox

sorry for my english, i do not speak this language very well. My question - is it even possible to use the Shield UI widget NumericTextBox as a parser for entering numbers with decimal points? I have not found a suitable parameter for it. When using the {0: n2} format, each number in the input is rounded, for example, 17.28 becomes 17, and the textbox returns 17.00, 123.78 becomes 124, and then 124.00. Thank you in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the `step` to some decimal too. Check the second numeric text box in [this example](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/numerictextbox/basic-usage) for a live demo.